# How to overcome Unindentation error in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have come acros the following error many times. Can anyone help me what to do when this error comes up?

Here I am attaching a screenshot.

[image: Here I am attaching The Code.]
[image: Error Statement]

Comment: Convert tabs to 4 spaces from your IDE

Comment: You can use an IDE specific to python such as pycharm which auto-indents when you hit enter and will give you an error if you have indented incorrectly. https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: if you are saying that error is because of not leaving spaces,no.This comes when I copy some lines of code from one file to another.

Comment: I would wager you have an inconsistent mix of tabs and spaces. Your editor should have an option to view whitespace.  The problem should become clear once you view whitespace.

Comment: Your editor should also have settings for how it handles tabs and spaces that you type. Find a setting so that you can produce good indentation without having to worry over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) to solve the problem in those languages.

In `.editorconfig`, you can write the some rules for python

```
    # 4 space indentation
    [*.py]
    indent_style = space
    indent_size = 4
```

and save the `.editorconfig` in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It once happened to me when I - in order to make things shorter - cut and paste some sentences from another source. I had to rewrite them again and everything went fine. Obviously, Python is quite serious about indentantions.

Answer (score -1):

I normally do "select all" in my text editer, then indent, then unindent. The editor should convert all tabs to spaces (or spaces to tabs depending on the setting in your editor.

**Edited to address Steven's comment:** If you are using Notepad or some such you could do a find/replace for tabs or something?